# Varnish wrong version

Tags: apache, varnish

I'm using MACOS SIERRA,with apache server on it.
I installed the varnish on it with version 3.0.4
I want to update it to 5.1
When I type: brew install varnish on terminal ,it return `Warning: varnish 5.2.0 is already installed` 
But when I run varnishd -V ,the version still 3.0.4.
Please help

Comment: Uninstall it: `brew uninstall varnish`, then reinstall.